# Agm-marker does not work when uses values of a loop variable (ngFor)

Tags: angular, google-maps

Im using "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2" in my Angular application, but Im getting a problem related to the tag agm-marker

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
      <agm-marker *ngFor="let g of games" [latitude]="g.lat" [longitude]="g.lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

when i hardcode the value of latitude and longitude, it displays correctly the marker, when i use the variable 'g', it shows nothing. The variable 'games' comes from a RESTservice.

Comment: Can you please show what the value of `games` is?

Comment: 37.7664, -3.78833
37.76902, -3.78597
37.763081, -3.7934
37.76902, -3.78597, and the type of both parameters is number.

Comment: No, please post the actual code. Maybe you try passing an Observable of pointers instead of the pointers themselves, or something like that, this is pure speculation without more code

Comment: I have changed in my class the type of the parameters lat, lng, and now instead of number Im using Number. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem lays on the type i was using for the input for agm-marker. Using *Number* instead of *number* solves the problem.